# JuMP variable declaration: MethodError

Tags: julia, julia-jump

I'm following the [quickstart guide](http://www.juliaopt.org/JuMP.jl/0.18/quickstart.html) on JuMP.

My julia version is 0.7, the code is this:

```
using JuMP

m = Model()

l = zeros(10)
u = ones(10)

#@variable(m, x)
#@variable(m, 0 <= x[1:10] <= 1)
@variable(m, l<=x[1:10]<=u)
```

The first two variable macros (commented out) work fine, but the last one produces an error.

```
MethodError: no method matching constructvariable!(::Model, ::getfield(JuMP, Symbol("#_error#107")){Tuple{Symbol,Expr}}, ::Array{Float64,1}, ::Array{Float64,1}, ::Symbol, ::String, ::Float64)
Closest candidates are:
  constructvariable!(::Model, ::Function, !Matched::Number, !Matched::Number, ::Symbol, ::AbstractString, ::Number; extra_kwargs...) at /home/lhk/.julia/packages/JuMP/Xvn0n/src/macros.jl:968
  constructvariable!(::Model, ::Function, !Matched::Number, !Matched::Number, ::Symbol, !Matched::Number, !Matched::Array{T,1} where T, !Matched::Array{Float64,1}, !Matched::AbstractString, !Matched::Number; extra_kwargs...) at /home/lhk/.julia/packages/JuMP/Xvn0n/src/macros.jl:961

Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope at /home/lhk/.julia/packages/JuMP/Xvn0n/src/macros.jl:1259
 [2] top-level scope at In[18]:7
```

How can I have different bounds for each entry in a vector valued variable ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Argh, this is actually really easy:

```
l = zeros(10)
u = ones(10)
@variable(m, l[idx] <= x[idx = 1:10] <= u[idx])
```